# read specific element from the xml string?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, winforms

I have a xml string stored in database as

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>1</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 1</Product_name>
    <Product_price>1000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>2</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 2</Product_name>
    <Product_price>2000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>3</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 3</Product_name>
    <Product_price>3000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>4</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 4</Product_name>
    <Product_price>4000</Product_price>
  </Product>
</Table>

  Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xmlstring))
```

where xmlstring is String contains above xml data.
 How to directly read product at id 4 ?

Comment: you can use reader.read method..

Comment: No, I don't want to use this. because each and every time I have to Loop for the element, Which i hate Most. Is there any direct function to go to the element at specific id?

Comment: Is this DataSet XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`XDocument.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to do that easily, without having to traverse through XML elements manually :

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse("your xml string here")
Dim product = doc.Root _
                 .Elements("Product") _
                 .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Element("Product_id").Value = "4")
'at this point, product contain the desired <Product> element'
'you can get product name this way :'
Dim productName = product.Element("Product_name").Value
```

**UPDATE :**

Since `XDocument` isn't available in .NET 2.0, We have to move to the older `XmlDocument`. For those who are familiar with XPath, this can even be simpler :

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring)

Dim productName = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Table/Product[Product_id='4']/Product_name") _
                     .InnerText
```

The XPath used in above example means, search `<Product>` node having child node `<Product_id>` equals to 4, then from that `<Product>` get `Product_name>` child

Comment: It only works with dot net framework 3.5 and above. Its not working in my application because its in Framework 2.0 and i Cant change to 3.5 :(

Comment: Can i achieve the same in application of framework 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't what do use loops then I think it's better to use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead. Spice this up with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) and the problem is solved.

```vb
Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

document.LoadXml(xmlstring)

Dim match As XmlNode = (
    From
        node As XmlNode
    In
        document.SelectNodes("/Table/Product").Cast(Of XmlNode)()
    Where
        node.SelectNodes("Product_id")(0).InnerText = "4"
    Select
        node
).FirstOrDefault()

If (match Is Nothing) Then
    'No match
Else
    'Found
End If
```

---

**.Net 2.0**

Using a `For Each` loop:

```vb
Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

document.LoadXml(xmlstring)

Dim match As XmlNode = Nothing

For Each node As XmlNode In document.SelectNodes("/Table/Product")
    If (node.SelectNodes("Product_id")(0).InnerText = "4") Then
        match = node
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If (match Is Nothing) Then
    'No match
Else
    'Found
End If
```

Comment: Its showing error 'Cast is not a member of System.Xml.XmlNodeList' . Is there any way to do the same in framework 2.0 ?

Comment: @ErMayank You're correct, this will not work with `.Net 2.0`.Please see my edit.